# Variable type in JSON using Jersey+MOXy

Tags: java, json, jersey, moxy

I am writing REST services using Jersey and MOXy.
I need to create a JSON array of objects that looks like this:

```
{
    indexes:[
    {
       "name": "ABC",
       "value": "abcdef"
       "displayValue": "abcdef",
       "type": "string"
     },
     {
        "name": "XYZ",
        "value": 12345
        "displayValue": "12345",
        "type": "number"
     },
     ...
     ]
}
```

The string-type should be quoted while the "number"-type should be un-quoted.

I tried to return the following POJO in the service request:

```
public class Index {
    String name;
    Object value;
    String displayValue;
    String type;
}
```

I defined the setValue to assign either Integer, or String to value, based on "type".
Similarly, I defined getValue to return either Integer or String.

Here is my output, that, non-surprisingly, creates another level of curly braces:

```
{
     indexes:[
     {
          "name": "ABC",
      "value": {
          "type": "xsd:string",
          "value": "abcdef"
      },
      "displayValue": "abcdef",
      "indexType": "string"
     },
     {
          "name": "XYZ",

          "value": {
            "type": "xsd:int",
            "value": 812501
        },
     "displayValue": "812501",
     "indexType": "number"
     },
     ...
```

Is there any way to achieve what I need, variable type value for the "value" field?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where your problem is exactly. What JSON library are you using? Also, could you provide more details about your Index class? I am not sure why your setValue(Object value) would need to do anything special. If I use the Jackson json library with the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    Index[] indices = new Index[2];
    indices[0] = new Index();
    indices[0].name = "ABC";
    indices[0].value = "abcdef";
    indices[0].displayValue = indices[0].value + "";
    indices[0].type = "string";
    indices[1] = new Index();
    indices[1].name = "XYZ";
    indices[1].value = 123456;
    indices[1].displayValue = indices[1].value + "";
    indices[1].type = "number";
    System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(indices));
}

public static class Index {

    String name;
    Object value;
    String displayValue;
    String type;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Object getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Object value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getDisplayValue() {
        return displayValue;
    }

    public void setDisplayValue(String displayValue) {
        this.displayValue = displayValue;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

I get the following output:

```
[{"name":"ABC","value":"abcdef","displayValue":"abcdef","type":"string"},
 {"name":"XYZ","value":123456,"displayValue":"123456","type":"number"}]
```

Which I believe is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes, your example is exactly what I need. However, I do not use Jackson (this is not my decision) but MOXy that produces "type" for an Object.

Comment: Also, I am not converting POJO to JSON directly; I return the POJO as a service response, so MOXy does its magic afterwards.